# probability combination

Tags: probability

McGyver is faced with the problem of opening a safe with 10 buttons numbered from 0 to 9. The safe can be opened by pressing three buttons, not necessarily distinct, in correct order. Realizing that the probability of getting the right combination is too small McGyver thought of a way of swinging the odds in his favor. He pulverized the lead from a pencil and blew the powder onto the buttons, revealing three buttons that have been pressed many times before. What is the probability that McGyver will be able to open the safe in a single trial?

Comment: Now MyGyver knows that the combination is made of three numbers, say 4, 1 and 3. Since he has one trial, the probability will be 1 / the number of ways you can permute 3 items. And that is ....

Comment: $\frac{1}{3!}$.